# Will process lost wake-up chance in a preemptive kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, sleep, race-condition

Usually, when processes want to wait some events that are not available, we can put them into sleep and wake up them later when the events occur.

The familiar codes below fulfil this task:

```
while (!events) {
    DEFINE_WAIT(wait);

    prepare_to_wait(&q, &wait, TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);
    if (!events)
        schedule();
    finish_wait(&q, &wait);
}
```

Imagine that in a **preemptive kernel** there exists two processes in which process A is a producer and process B is a consumer. Process B is executing the codes above, waiting for the some datas produced by process A become valid.

Now, I think process B will lost the wake-up chance if the executing path of two processes is as below.

1. Process B checks event in `while` statement, and now it is return false.
2. Process B executes `DEFIN_WAIT(wait)`.
3. Process A produces some datas just after process B finished executing `DEFIN_WAIT(wait)` and before executing `prepare_to_wait(&q, &wait, TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);`.
4. Process B executes `prepare_to_wait(&q, &wait, TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);`.
5. Process B is preempted by other process just before it executes `if (!events)`.

Because of the state of process B now is `TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE`, it won't be schedule to CPU again. So, I think, Process B will never be waken....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your final verdict is wrong: preemption does not work with task state. So, even in `TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE` state preempted task can gain CPU again.

See, e.g [this](http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0304.1/1606.html) or [that](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212004/can-a-kernel-preemption-happen-in-the-process-context-with-task-interruptible).

Comment: <http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0304.1/1612.html> also helps me. Thanks you, Tsyvarev.